# Delete row in aldeed tabular Meteor

Tags: meteor, tabular

Im using meteor and the aldeed tabular package. I have succeed to add data in the tabular from mongodb. I wonder if there is a way to delete / hide the row without deleting the data in mongodb?? Does anyone have an idea?? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add a flag/field to your collection -> `DeletedYN` and the value can be true or false.
Then when retrieving your collection use a filter on `DeletedYN`.
This concept is called logic deletion, and will also be manual work.